# How to compare member id and bots id on the server

Tags: discord.js

I get the ids of all bots on the server but I can't compare them with the user id
How do I do this?

-- Comment --
I know that I can't compare the user id with the id of all bots just by writing this, but I don't know how to compare the user id with each id in the list
-- Part of the code --

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("pay")
        .setDescription("│Дать деньги другому пользователю")
        .addNumberOption((option) => option.setName("amount").setDescription("│Кол-во денег которое хочешь перевести").setRequired(true))
        .addUserOption((option) => option.setName("target").setDescription("│Выбрать кому перевести деньги").setRequired(true))
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const target = interaction.options.getUser("target")
        const member = await interaction.guild.members.cache.get(target.id)
        const bots = await interaction.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.user.bot).map(i => i.user.id)

        if (!member) {
            await interaction.reply({ content: "**│The user is not identified or he has left the server**" }).then(() => {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    await interaction.deleteReply().catch((error) => {
                        if (error.code !== RESTJSONErrorCodes.UnknownMessage) {
                            return
                        } else {
                            return
                        }
                    })
                }, ms("3s"))
            })
        } else if (member.user.id == interaction.user.id) {
            await interaction.reply({ content: "**│You can't transfer money to yourself**" }).then(() => {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    await interaction.deleteReply().catch((error) => {
                        if (error.code !== RESTJSONErrorCodes.UnknownMessage) {
                            return
                        } else {
                            return
                        }
                    })
                }, ms("3s"))
            })
        } else if (member.user.id == bots || member.user.id == interaction.guild.members.me.id) {
            await interaction.reply({ content: "**│You can't transfer money to a bot**" }).then(() => {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    await interaction.deleteReply().catch((error) => {
                        if (error.code !== RESTJSONErrorCodes.UnknownMessage) {
                            return;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    })
                }, ms("3s"))
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`.bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User?scrollTo=bot) property on the `User Class` which you can use like this:

```js
if(member.user.bot) {
  // Do something if bot
}
```

Using this, will be easier to check whether the user is a bot or not.

Comment: I really forgot this solution method and for some reason started comparing the target ID and bots. Thanks